# Raphael JS Sketchpad Not Working

Tags: javascript, raphael

So I'm having the same problem as this user: [Rapahel Sketchpad not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595404/rapahel-sketchpad-not-working)

But his solution isn't working.

I'm running a node app.js file on my localhost to try to save these Raphael sketchpad images as a json. However, no sketchpad is appearing even when I copy and paste this documentation code....

I suspect it may be the way my javascript is linked? I have a views folder with handlebars files and I also have a public/js folder, where should the files I want go and what should they be named specifically and where should I get them?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had multiple jQuery files... if you just use the Google API one from the post I referred to then that should work.  I put all my javascript calls in the header.